# User authentication for printer in macOS Ventura

Tags: network, printing, ventura

Our company provides a network printer which can be accessed freely from the local network. But to actually fetch printouts (after authenticating with an ID card at the printer), one has to specify a login name in the macOS printing dialog (so the print job is placed in the correct queue). The relevant configuration pane in the dialog was accessible in Monterey (and earlier), but I cannot find it in Ventura. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without at least knowing the model of printer. But if you have a look through the print panel, it should be there somewhere. Click on all the discovery arrows. Don't forget that the 'info' i circles yield dialogs with more settings.

Comment: I suggest you ask your company Tech Support. Not knowing the structure of your network print server system, nor how you provide authentication, it is hard to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Our company tech support provides only rudimentary support for Macs (in this case, a screenshot from some earlier version of macOS), and they won't track the changes in macOS Ventura upon request. I did investigate the print dialog thoroughly, of course, and the option is not to be found behind all the arrows and info circles. I am quite sure it was moved somewhere else.